# Syntax highlighting partially working on VS Code for C#

Tags: c#, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code

I have a laptop and a pc. Both have a very minimal installation of Visual Studio Code, same version.

The laptop shows a C# file in this way:

[image: http://imgur.com/OHn5w1o]

The pc shows the same C# file in this other way:

[image]

Obviously, I prefer the laptop version. But I can't get the PC to color the text in the same way.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Very likely to be caused by a corrupt extension installation on the PC. Can you remove and install C# extension again?

Comment: Tried that already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VS Code comes with 2 dark and 2 light themes (`Dark`, `Dark+`, `Light` and `Light+`). On your laptop, the `Dark+` theme is active, on your PC, it's the `Dark` theme.

### Changing the Theme

In VS Code on your PC, press <kbd>F1</kbd>, enter `Theme`, select `Preferences: Color Theme`, select `Dark+` from the dropdown and you should be fine.

You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the theme dropdown.